# Web Apps Script: No output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I am trying to display a Google Visualization GeoMap on my website. I created the code in the Code Playground and saved it as an Apps Script in my website. The page goes through the load process but nothing is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    function drawVisualization() {
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        'https://docs.google.com/a/mantisnetworks.co/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoNHsySj5NxGdGt0dmxva3ZPb3dLYVpVZ2Z4TThNbGc&usp=drive_web#gid=0');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response){
  if(response.isError()){
    alert('Error in Query:' + response.getMessage()+''+response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

      var data = response.getDataTable();

      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('visualization'));

      var options = {};
      options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
      options['resolution'] = 'provinces';
      options['region'] = 'LS';
      options['width'] = '600px';
      options['height'] = '300px';

      geochart.draw(data, options);
    }


  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Read the apps script tutorials regarding app design in gas. you are putting the code server-side but that code will only ever work client-side, thus you would need to use htmlServices thou I doubt the google vizualization libs will work in there because of caja issues. In the tutorials you will find other builtin ways to visualize data.

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script is based on Javascript, but as a server-side environment it does not have access to all client-side javascript constructs. The Google visualizations, for instance, are provided as the [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/). Using that service, you'll find support for much of the visualization API. However, you won't find GeoMap.

The code you've provided in your question needs to be reworked considerably to work properly in Google Apps Script. Start with the example given on the Charts Service page, then adapt to your situation.

You do have another alternative within Google Apps Script, which is to use the HTML service to "host" an HTML page containing "real" javascript. Javascript that's embedded in HTML pages can be made to run on the client browser, so the example you cooked up in the playground *should* work. A full run-down of this option is beyond the scope of your question, but if you're interested in it you could start by scanning [previous questions about the HTML Service](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20%22HTML%20service%22%20is:question).